# Stream connection lost: AssertionError(('_AsyncTransportBase._produce() tx buffer size underflow', -275, 1),)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pika

This error occurs when many requests are made to be published

error: Stream connection lost: AssertionError(('_AsyncTransportBase._produce() tx buffer size underflow', -275, 1),)

```
@name_space.route('/gravar-coleta-lista-hoteis')
class GravarColetaListaHoteis(Resource):
    def post(self):
        try:
            data = request.get_json()
            rabbitMQProducerService.publish(data, QueueNameConst.queue_name_hotel)
            return "ok"
```

```
class RabbitMQProducerService:
connection = None
channel = None
persistence_dao_mongo = None
rabbitmq_host = None
credentials = None

def __init__(self, rabbitmq_host, rabbitmq_user, rabbitmq_password):
    self.rabbitmq_host = rabbitmq_host
    self.credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(rabbitmq_user, rabbitmq_password)
    self.connect()

def publish(self, body, queue_name):
    if self.channel.is_closed:
        self.connect()
    self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                               routing_key=queue_name,
                               body=json.dumps(body))

def connect(self):
    self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(
        host=self.rabbitmq_host,
        credentials=self.credentials))
    self.channel = self.connection.channel()
```

Comment: Hi @Gustavo Did you get resolution for the same.

Comment: In my case, this error was happening because I shared my connection across two threads. Pika is not thread-safe which means you should not share your connection across multiple threads as it can lead to unexpected behavior. Therefore, you should make unique connection per thread instead of using same connection across multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* because of threading.  Use conn.connection.add_callback_threadsafe

```
def callback_publish(ch):
    ch.basic_publish(exchange='',
                     routing_key='foo',
                     body='{"response": "success"}')


cb = functools.partial(callback_publish, ch)
conn.connection.add_callback_threadsafe(cb)
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to create two instances of my class `Queue` or your class `RabbitMQProducerService` with an init variable of `listener: bool = True` where one was True and the other False to be able to send data in both directions since pika isn't safe with threading as said by Syed in the comments of the question.